# Pytest - how to mock 3rd party class instead of monkeypatching

Tags: python, mocking, patch, monkeypatching

To be specific, I'm using the python [O365](https://github.com/O365/python-o365) library in a custom SharePoint repository. It heavily relies on some classes from this library and I need to mock out functionalities since I can't just connect to any real resources in my tests.

Here is the key part of my repository.

```
class SharepointRepository():
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self._account = Account(
          ...
        ) # O365.account.Account

    sites = self._account.sharepoint().search_site(app.config.get("SP_SITE"))
    self._site = sites[0] # O365.sharepoint.Site

    def _get_drive_by_name(self, drive_name):
        for drive in self._site.list_document_libraries():
            if drive.name == drive_name:
                return drive

    def delete_file(self, drive, path):
        item = drive.get_item_by_path(path) # O365.drive.Drive
        if not item.delete(): # O365.drive.DriveItem
            raise Exception(
```

I've tried to `monkeypatch` the called methods from the library one by one, but the problem is that these attribute objects are created by the library itself and would already make real connections. So I can't just create or inject them myself.

```
import pytest
from O365.account import Account
from O365.sharepoint import Site
from O365.drive import Drive

class TestSharePoint:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self):
        self.client = SharepointRepository()
        self.drive_name = "test drive"
        self.path = "test path"
        self._account = Account() # This does not work, I need to mock this.
        self._site = Site() # This does not work, I need to mock this.

    def test_sharepoint_file_delete(self, monkeypatch):
        def get_drive(drive_name):
            assert drive_name == self.drive_name

        def get_item(drive, path):
            assert drive == self.drive_name
            assert path == self.path

        with NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
            monkeypatch.setattr(Site, "list_document_libraries", get_drive)
            monkeypatch.setattr(Drive, "get_item_by_path", get_item)

            self.client.delete_file(file, self.drive_name, self.path)
```

How can I mock these library classes with their methods instead of trying to patch every single method this way?

Comment: If you inverted the dependency it would be easier to test - `SharepointRepository` shouldn't _create_ an instance of `O365.account.Account`, for example, it should be _given_ one.

Comment: I can't give one either. It is created from complex credentials and it instantly connects to an O365  account. Which I can't provide for testing.

Comment: Yes, but if the instance is being passed into `__init__` rather than created within it you can provide a _test double_ in the tests, not a real instance. You can also create your own facade around the interfaces you don't own, and inject a test double of that for testing.

Comment: I can't break this pattern unfortunately, because I have to follow an interface implementation. I just left that out for simplicity from the class header.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"I have to follow an interface implementation"*.

Comment: I mean this is just one repository implementation for O365 Sharepoint and I have an interface for many different repositories which won't have any `Account` around, only the `app`.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's a problem, `SharepointRepository` can still implement whatever that interface is. If there's other context that will impact solutions, [edit] the question to provide it.

Comment: I won't have an `Account` where I'm going to use this. That layer has nothing to do with any of the actual implementation in use - provided by config vars. But I'd like to ask: that test double would be also a mock isn't it?

Comment: Then maybe there's a class method e.g. `from_app` that creates the instances of those other dependencies and makes an instance of the repository, but from what you've posted we can't see what if anything `Account` even needs. A mock is a type of test double, see e.g. https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/pivotal-engineering-journal/the-test-double-rule-of-thumb-2

Comment: I did not want to dilute the question with that part, but yes: Every repository gets only the `app` which has the proper configs bound on it. This `Account` needs these configs as well, but that's the repo's job how it handles it. So I inject the data via the `app`. 
I'm reading (similar questions)(https://stackoverflow.com/a/39004889/6560773) now and trying to mock them the same way.